# Delete sublist containing False

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list in the form

```
{{A,B,False},{D,C,True},{E,F,True},{G,H,False}}
```

I want to delete all the sublists containing `False`.
That is, after the applying the function I would like to have the list

```
{{D,C,True},{E,F,True}}
```

I've tried using `DeleteCases`, but I can't get it to work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `C`, `D` and `E` have reserved meaning in Mathematica.

Comment: I know, but the list that I have have basically arbitrary data (string, functions etc.).

Comment: Also just for this particular case: `Pick[#,#[[All,-1]]]&@lst`

Comment: `Pick[list, Last /@ list]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use DeleteCases

```
{{A,B,False},{D,C,True},{E,F,True},{G,H,False}} // DeleteCases[{___, False, ___}]
```

> {{D, C, True}, {E, F, True}}

use Select

```
{{A,B,False},{D,C,True},{E,F,True},{G,H,False}} // Select[Not @* MemberQ[False]]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Pick[alist, ContainsNone[{False}][#] & /@ alist]

Pick[alist, ContainsAny[{False}][#] & /@ alist, False]

DeleteCases[alist, _?(ContainsAny[{False}])]

Cases[alist, _?(FreeQ[False])]
```

> {{D, C, True}, {E, F, True}}

Answer (score 6):

In this particular case:

list = {{a, b, False}, {d, c, True}, {e, f, True}, {g, h, False}};

```
Select[Last] @ list
```

{{d, c, True}, {e, f, True}}

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `GroupBy`:

```
lst = {{A,B,False},{D,C,True},{E,F,True},{G,H,False}};

Last@GroupBy[lst, MemberQ[False]]

(*{{D, C, True}, {E, F, True}}*)
```

Or using `Extract`:

```
Extract[#, Position[#, x_List /; FreeQ[x, False]]] &[lst]

(*{{D, C, True}, {E, F, True}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
lst = {{a, b, False}, {d, c, True}, {e, f, True}, {g, h, False}};

lst /. {___, False, ___} -> Nothing
```

> {{d, c, True}, {e, f, True}}